# unknown function already exists error

Tags: c++

I have a strange error when i compiled my code it says the member function alreadys exist within another classes which it does not the error says

> Error LNK2005 "public: void __thiscall membershipType::print(void)"
>   (?print@membershipType@@QAEXXZ) already defined in
>   personType.obj    Project1    C:\Users\okpal\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Source.obj

and also

> Error LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols
>   found Project1    C:\Users\okpal\source\repos\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe 1

i was wondering if anyone could help figure out the error
my class code is below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class addressType {  //class defintions and prototypes member variables
public:
    addressType();
    string streetAddressNum, streetName, streetType, city, stateInitials;
    int zipCode;
};
class personType
{
public:
    personType();
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int personNum;
    char gender;
    int personID;
    addressType address;
    void setInterest1(string interest1);//mutator
    void setInterest2(string interest2);
    void printPerson();
    string  GetInterest1() const;    // Accessor
    string  GetInterest2() const;
private:
    string SetInterest1;
    string SetInterest2;
};
//define membershipType class
class membershipType :public personType
{
public:
    char membership_type;
    char membership_status;
    membershipType();  // 1st constructor
    membershipType(char, char);  // 2nd constructor
    void print();

};

void membershipType::print() 
{
    cout << GetInterest1();
}
```

the source code for persontype

```
#include "personType.h"
personType::personType()
{
    int personNum = 0;
    int personID = 0;
}
addressType::addressType() {
    int zipCode = 0;
}
void personType::setInterest1(string interest1) {
    SetInterest1 = interest1;
}//mutator
void personType::setInterest2(string interest2) {
    SetInterest2 = interest2;
}
string personType::  GetInterest1() const
{
    return SetInterest1;
}// Accessor
string personType:: GetInterest2() const {
    return SetInterest2;
}

void personType :: printPerson() {//constructor

    cout << firstName << " " << lastName << " " << gender << " " <<
        personID << " " << address.streetAddressNum << " "
        << address.streetName << " " << address.streetType
        << " " << address.city << " " << address.stateInitials
        << " " << address.zipCode << " " << SetInterest1 << " " << SetInterest2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Move definition of `print` to implementation file (.cpp)

Comment: alright finally it worked and i wanted to know why it worked?

Comment: Read about the [odr](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)

Answer (score 2):

You have the definition of `membershipType::print()` in the first code block, which I presume to be copied from a header file.  In C++, header files' contents are inserted into every file that includes them.  Presumably, you have at least two source files in your program that include this header.  When these source files get compiled to object files, both will then contain a definition of `membershipType::print()`.  When you try to link them, the linker will detect that both files contain definitions of the same symbol.  It doesn't know which to use where, so it returns an error.

The easiest way to fix this is to move the definition of `membershipType::print()` to a source file.  You can also fix it by making it inline.